# vue passing array of objects as props not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i am trying to pass an array of objects as vue props..
I can do this by

```
  props:{
        myStudentArray: {
            type:Array,
            required: true

        },
    }
```

How can i define the object as well here? so that i can access the properties? I want to tell the array is of type Student and student has this much properties

Comment: Do you really need to pass an array of objects? I don't know the whole project structure, but by default you pass the object to the component inside the loop.

Comment: Have to pass the array of objects itself.. in the parent function , they need it altogother

Comment: A third party library may help you then:
https://github.com/dwightjack/vue-types#vuetypesarrayof

Comment: oops..no other way?

Comment: If you want to verify that each array item is of type Student then you can use a [validator function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) and loop over them to validate their type.

Comment: think about typescript